# Append nextline to current line until pattern matched in awk

Tags: awk, sed

Input file data:

```
"1","123","hh
KKK,111,ll
Jk"
"2","124","jj"
```

Output data:

```
"1","123","hh KKK,111,ll jk"
"2","124","jj"
```

Tried below code in awk file. still not working for desired output:

```
BEGIN{
      `FS="\",\"";
        record_lock_flag=0;
        total_feilds=3;
        tmp_field_count=0;
        tmp_rec_buff="";
        lines=0;
        }
        {
        if(NR>0)
        {
        if( record_lock_flag == 0 && NF == total_feilds && substr($NF,length($NF)-1,length($NF)) ~ /^"/  )
                 {
        print $0;
                }
        else
                {
        tmp_rec_buff=tmp_rec_buff$0 ;
        tmp_field_count=tmp_field_count+NF ;
        if ( $0 != "")
        { lines++ ;}
        rec_lock_flag=1 ;
                 if(tmp_field_count==exp_fields+lines-1){
                                print tmp_rec_buff;
                                record_lock_flag=0;
                                tmp_field_count=0;
                                tmp_rec_buff="";
                                lines=0;
                                                        }
                }
        }
        }
        END{
        }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` setting `ORS`:

```
awk '{ORS = (!/"$/) ? " " : "\n"} 1' file
"1","123","hh KKK,111,ll Jk"
"2","124","jj"
```

Answer (score 3):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\""} !(NR%2){gsub(/\n/," ")} 1' file
"1","123","hh KKK,111,ll Jk"
"2","124","jj"
```

See also [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Answer (score 2):

Using `gnu-awk` we can break records using text `"\n"` then remove `\n` from each record and finally append `"\n"` in the end using same `ORS` (assuming there are no blank fields with opening and closing quotes on separate lines):

```sh
awk -v RS='"\n("|$)' '{gsub(/\n/, " "); ORS=RT} 1' file

"1","123","hh KKK,111,ll Jk"
"2","124","jj"
```

---

Another version using `gnu-awk` if you already know number of fields in each record as shown in your question:

```sh
awk -v n=3 -v FPAT='"[^"]*"' 'p {$0 = p " " $0; p=""}
NF < n {p = $0; next} 1' file

"1","123","hh KKK,111,ll Jk"
"2","124","jj"
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only, you could try following `awk` code. Written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    sum+=gsub(/"/,"&",$i)
    val=(val?val OFS:"")$i
    if(sum%2==0){
      print val
      sum=0
      val=""
    }
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '    ##Starting awk program from here, setting RS as NULL and field separator as new line.
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){        ##Traversing through all fields here.
    sum+=gsub(/"/,"&",$i)    ##Globally substituting " with itself and keeping its count to sum variable.
    val=(val?val OFS:"")$i   ##Creating val which has current field in it and keep appending its value to it.
    if(sum%2==0){            ##Checking if sum is even number then do following.
      print val              ##Printing val here.
      sum=0                  ##Setting sum to 0 here.
      val=""                 ##Nullifying val here.
    }
  }
}
' Input_file                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```